Corn snake went nuts than died. What happened?
I fed my 6 year old corn snake as per usual. He is a very active boy. After his feeding he went nuts like I’ve never seen before. Flying all over his enclosure. I feel like maybe he choked?? Initially I thought he was having a seizure. Any thoughts. My poor Tigg is gone. 

I don't think there's any way we can diagnose this remotely, and I don't know snakes well enough to have an opinion. But your guess sounds reasonable to me.
